# How to find missing resource files (.resx) entries in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, resources, translation

I often have to extend my resource files with additional entries.Then you have to do that for all the other languages, but obviously, sometimes you forget some entries.

How do other people check if all the resource files for different languages have the same entries?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's nothing built into VS to assist with this. You need to manually check yourself or rely on a 3rd-party [resx localization tool](http://www.hexadigm.com) (I'm the author of this product).